# Select multiple columns but group by should be on only one column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT DISTINCT DRUG_NAME, SUM(WEIGHT) FROM FIR

              INNER JOIN USER_LOGIN ON FIR.USER_ID = USER_LOGIN.USER_ID
              INNER JOIN POLICE_STATION ON FIR.PS_ID = POLICE_STATION.PS_ID
              INNER JOIN DRUG_INFO ON FIR.FIR_NO = DRUG_INFO.FIR_NO

              WHERE WEIGHT != 0 AND DRUG_FORM = 'Litres (l)'
              GROUP BY DRUG_NAME
              )
```

I want a group by on `drug_name` but want these columns in the select `drug_form,weight,picture,username`. The above sql statement is working fine but i can't select `drug_form,weight,picture,username` columns.

**i want to combine drug name like opium together and show there total count on 1 column.**

[image: <code>pic</code>]

[image: <code>pic3</code>]

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  If you want to show the username for example, but don't want to group on it, which should return if there are multiple?

Comment: 2 mins i will provide u

Comment: You have Distinct plus a GROUP BY, that seems unnecessary.

Comment: post your table schema.

Comment: wait 2 mins i wil tak a pic

Comment: @Rahul check the post

Comment: Would you mind giving a try again.

Comment: @Rahul i posted the resulted pic above. will you tell me how grouping is done. because i didn't get it. opium showing in 4-5 columns. is this can be done in a way that. group by drug form and drug name and count the total weight

Answer (score 0):

Any column that isn't in your group by clause must use an aggregate function (MAX, AVG, SUM, etc) . Since you're "grouping" multiple values into a single column, you need some way to condense the data down to a single value.

Either put the other columns into your group by, or use an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like this (Not tested though)

```
SELECT d.drug_form,
d.weight,
ull.picture,
ull.username,
x.DRUG_NAME,
x.TotalWeight
FROM DRUG_INFO d inner join FIR f
on d.FIR_NO = f.FIR_NO
inner join USER_LOGIN ull
on f.USER_ID = ull.USER_ID
inner join
(SELECT DRUG_NAME,
 SUM(WEIGHT) as TotalWeight 
 FROM DRUG_INFO    
 WHERE WEIGHT != 0 
 AND DRUG_FORM = 'Litres (l)'
 GROUP BY DRUG_NAME
 ) x
on d.DRUG_NAME = x.DRUG_NAME
```

Comment: its saying column unabmigiously defined

Comment: column33 line12 ORA-00918

Comment: @user3400389, try now. it was because of `group by user_id` since that column exist in other joining table as well.

Comment: @now line:5 cloumn:27 this time 'now line:5 cloumn:27'

Comment: latest: 'line:9 column 61'

Comment: `FIR.DRUG_NAME` this should be `drug_info.DRUG_NAME`

Comment: @user3400389, check now. all this error was because of not using table alias properly. change it accordingly, wherevr you find table name is different.

Comment: drug name only exists in drug info table

Comment: @user3400389, try again. I have no way of testing it. I am trying to get the sum separately in inner query and then trying to fetch all other columns using joins in outer query.

Comment: nope didn't work the right way. i posted the pic above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52625/discussion-between-rahul-and-user3400389)